# POSTing XML with SQL doesn't work but Postman works fine

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, postman

```
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- Send the request.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false';

--set a custom header Authorization is the header key and VALUE is the value in the header
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'SetRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader

--EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @postData;
-- Handle the response.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;
```

This doesn't work ("No XML data") in SQL Server 2008.

But all of these work(using the code function on Postman). Use whichever you know best to tell me where my SQL Server procedure is wrong:

C# - RestSharp

```
var client = new RestClient(<URL HERE>);
client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic <AUTH HERE>");
request.AddParameter("text/xml", "<XML HERE>,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Python - http.client

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(<URL START HERE>)
payload = "<XML HERE>"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
  'Authorization': 'Basic <AUTH HERE>'
}
conn.request("POST", "<URL END HERE>", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Javascript - jquery

```
var settings = {
  "url": "<URL HERE>",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml",
    "Authorization": "Basic <AUTH HERE>"
  },
  "data": "<XML HERE>",
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: SQL Server isn't really designed to call out to external services - what I'd recommend is calling that external service from your application/backend code (be it in C# or whatever), and then send the resulting XML down into SQL Server. And also: SQL Server **2008** is dead in the water and out of even extended support - **time to upgrade!**

Comment: Ugh, that sucks. Now I see why it worked last time. It was a modern SQL version. I tried the procedure there - and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because it was the old (2008) SQL server. Copied to a modern one and it worked fine.